# Scrapy: Pass argument to pipeline from CrawlerProcess

Tags: scrapy

I have a `CrawlerProcess` that launch the spider I want but I would like it to also pass the parameter `freq` to the pipeline.

```
process = CrawlerProcess(get_project_settings())
process.crawl(spider, freq=freq)
process.start()
```

I know that the way to get a parameter should be to use:

```
@classmethod
def from_crawler(cls, crawler):
```

But I have no idea how to get the `freq` parameter from there.
Any idea ?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Took me some time to figure it out but everything was actually in the [Core API](https://doc.scrapy.org/en/latest/topics/api.html) description of the method.

This solution is probably not the optimal one since I get the freq paramter from spider but it might be possible to grab it from the crawler directly if anyone has a better solution.

So the pipeline looks like:

```
class Pipeline(object):

    def __init__(self, freq):
        self.freq = freq

    @classmethod
    def from_crawler(cls, crawler):
        return cls(freq=crawler.spider.data_test)

    def open_spider(self, spider):
        return

    def process_item(self, item, spider):
        print("Freq:{}\n".format(self.freq))

    def close_spider(self, spider):
        return
```

What you have to do is encapsulate the variables you want to pass to pipeline in `cls`, give them a name, and in the `__init__`store them as class attribute. To be able to grab it from the spider, I had to store it also has an attribute in the spider:

```
class TestSpider(scrapy.Spider):
    name = "test"

    def __init__(self, freq):
        self.freq = freq
```

If you have some improvements on this solution, feel free to comment or offer a better one. I know it is not optimal.

Comment: I used the same solution

Comment: Then if you find it satisfactory, feel free to +1 :)

Comment: Of course, I wanted to let you know that it is an actually acceptable solution if you had any doubt

Comment: Ok thanks. I however still have doubt for the following reason: I have to pass the paramater `freq` all the way down to the spider before being able to grab it from the pipeline. Hence in my design, the spider will have to store it even though it might not need it.